# Display Tweets in Wordpress without the use of plugins

Tags: wordpress, twitter

Has anyone come across a clean way to post tweets in wordpress with the use of a plugin. I would like to have the flexibility to pull at least the top 5 and only display tweets with the assigned hash tag.

Many thanks

Comment: is it "with" or "without" a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this would give you the functionality to pull the most recent tweets from a hashtag, but it's totally doable to pull the most recent X updated from any user. Here's a couple of examples I found for you, written in php:

[Example One](https://web.archive.org/web/20110305155250/http://leebaillie.com/display-tweets-on-your-wordpress-blog-without-plugins-or-widgets)

[Example Two](http://www.instantshift.com/2009/05/25/10-twitter-hacks-for-your-wordpress-blog/) (Scroll down to #6)

Removing the "*from:*" in the second example's search string *should* allow you to search for any word or hashtag instead of by username, but I'm not 100% sure.

Fair warning though, that makes a prominent area of your site easily spammable. Anyone can post to a hashtag, right?

Comment: ah thank you, I did try Sample One, but I was going wrong somewhere as nothing displayed. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Regards to the hashtag, I would like to somehow tell it to display tweets from user x with #sample.

Comment: You'll have to fiddle with the search syntax a bit and add a second variable of $hashtag = "#justinbieber" to append, but that should be totally doable.